# Want Closed Form for an Integral/Summation

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation, improper-integrals

I am working on a mathematical model looks like this

$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty {A\over e^{(k-r)t}B + e^{kt}C}$$

$k,r$ are fixed real numbers, $k-r$ is positive, $t$ is the index, and $A,B,C$ are non-zero constants.

I feel difficulty find a closed form for that. I try to use integral test to pound it since $i-r$ is positive.

However, I am not able to calculate the following integral:

$$\int_{t=1}^\infty {A\over e^{(k-r)t}B + e^{kt}C}$$

So I wonder whether I will be able to get a closed for my original summation?
Could anyone help on this?

Really appreciated!

Comment: You say $i-r$ is positive. Does this mean that $i$ is not the complex number, but just stands for some fixed real number? If so suggest a different notation.

Comment: $i$ is not a complex number, it just stands fro some fixed real number.Already edited. Thx!

Comment: $t$ is the index.

Comment: If $A$, $B$ or $C$ is zero the integral is a breeze. I'm guessing they are all nonzero?

Comment: @graydad They are non-zeo

Comment: If you're just checking convergence for the sum, your integral can be bounded and the resulting larger integral converges.